# Why does "chmod 1777" and "chmod 3777" both set the sticky bit?

Tags: permissions, chmod

To set the sticky bit on a directory, why do the commands `chmod 1777` and `chmod 3777` both work?

Comment: You are proposing a potentially risky operation.The combination sticky bit and rwx permisions for all is bad practice. Anybody can change and execute the file and the s-bit allow switching to root user without pasword.

Comment: @jippie setuid and setgid bits go away if the file is modified, so you can't get root access that way.

Comment: @KyleJones, it's still dangerous.  If the `passwd` binary were world-writable, you wouldn't be able to get root access by modifying it, as you say, but you *could* replace it with some other binary that everyone would run thereafter, thinking it was `passwd`.

Comment: @Wildcard Agreed.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
     1            1             1         1   1   1      1   1   1      1   1   1
___________   __________   __________    ___ ___ ___    ___ ___ ___    ___ ___ ___ 
setUID bit    setGID bit   sticky bit     user           group          others
```

Each number (also referred to as an octal because it is base8) in that grouping represents 3 bits.  If you turn it into binary it makes it a lot easier.

1 = 0 0 1
3 = 0 1 1
5 = 1 0 1
7 = 1 1 1

So if you did 1777, 3777, 5777, or 7777 you would set the sticky bit because the third column would be a 1.  However, with 3777, 5777, and 7777 you are additionally setting other bits (SUID for the first column, and SGID for the second column).

Conversely, any other number in that spot (up to the maximum of 7) would not set the sticky bit because the last column wouldn't be a 1 or "on."

2 = 0 1 0
4 = 1 0 0
6 = 1 1 0

Comment: +1 for a nice description of how octal numbers work and how it applies to the file permission bits.

Comment: It's called "bitmask", and +1 also for explaining/showing how it can set and `clear` the Owner Group & Other columns.

Answer (score 17):

The permissions passed as an argument to chmod are specified as an [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) value.  Each numeral in the value represents three bits.  If three numerals are given, you're setting the read, write and execute bits for the file's owner, group and others (everyone else).  If four numerals are given, the leftmost number sets the setuid, setgid and sticky bits.  Octal 1 sets the sticky bit.  Octal 2 sets the setgid bit.  Octal 2 + octal 1 is octal 3 which sets both the setgid bit and the sticky bit.

Comment: Isn't it octal 2 | octal 1 rather than octal 2 + octal 1? The operations happen to have the same result in this case, but in general it's a bitwise or that matters, isn't it?

Comment: @gerrit Yes, in the general case you should be looking at the `binary or` operator. However, as you point out, in this case it works out to the same result, and plenty more people are familiar with addition.